# Deallocating images created with UIGraphicsBeginImageContext

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation, dealloc

I'm creating images array for UIImageView so I can use `[_myImageView startAnimating];` method. I figuree out that if I cache(preload) it like this way the animation is fluent.

But in Instruments I see, that game is deallocated but there is still too much memory allocated - I think there are some fragments of this UIGraphicsBeginContext stuff.

Am I using it right, is there some other way how to dealloc it? 
Thanks in advance!

```
- (NSMutableArray *)generateCachedImageArrayWithFilename:(NSString *)filename extension:(NSString *)extension andImageCount:(int)count
{

    _imagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    _fileExtension = extension;
    _animationImageName = filename;
    _imageCount = count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        NSString *tempImageNames = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i", filename, i];
        NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:tempImageNames ofType:extension];

        UIImage *frameImage = [self loadRetinaImageIfAvailable:imagePath];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(frameImage.size);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, frameImage.size.width, frameImage.size.height);
        [frameImage drawInRect:rect];
        UIImage *renderedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];

        if (_isDoublingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }
        else if (_isTriplingFrames)
        {
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
            [_imagesArray addObject:renderedImage];
        }

        NSLog(@"filename = %@", filename);
    }

    return _imagesArray;
}


- (UIImage *)loadRetinaImageIfAvailable:(NSString *)path
{

    NSString *retinaPath = [[path stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@2x.%@", [[path lastPathComponent] stringByDeletingPathExtension], [path pathExtension]]];

    if ([UIScreen mainScreen].scale == 2.0 && [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:retinaPath] == YES)
        return [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:retinaPath]] CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
    else
        return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
}

-(void) dealloc
{
    [_imagesArray removeAllObjects];
    _imagesArray = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had memory issues similar you wrote and what I would try out in your code

1) use `@autoreleasepool`

to wrap either the method or the content of the loop in `@autoreleasepool { }` to create a local pool which will be released after method is done. In your situation it seems to me wrapping the loop is better:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    @autoreleasepool {
    // the loop code
    ...
    }}
```

2) kill `[UIImage imageNamed]`

Using `imageNamed` will prepare a cache (depending on the size of image) which will never be flushed out of the memory unless you reach a memory warning. Even if you set myImage.image = nil, the image is still in memory. XCode's Intruments tool Allocations view will show it nicely. What you can do is initialize `UIImage` like this, and iOS won't cache the image:

```
image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullpath];
```

You might use `imageNamed` in your code under `loadRetinaImageIfAvailable`.

Keep both two approach and let's check this out again!